# How to remove visual studio 2012 addin menu?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, add-in

I'm making addin for visual studio 2012(C#).
I added a menu item with AddCommandBar method, then I changed the menu name.
After that previous menu was disabled but not removed.
I want to remove the addin menu but I can't.
I tried these links but they don't work.

devenv /resetaddin Namespace.ClassName
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228765(v=vs.110).aspx
[Dead items in context menu left by addin in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640867/dead-items-in-context-menu-left-by-addin-in-visual-studio)

Even I try to reinstall visual studio 2012 but still that menu is alive.
Tools -> Add-in Manager.. is disabled.
How can I remove that addin menu?

Answer (score 1):

I found this link.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2009/10/29/unable-to-uninstall-an-add-in-from-the-visual-studio-ide.aspx
With 'reset settings from Tools/Import and Export Settings', I can remove disabled addin menu.

Answer (score 0):

Find CurrentSetings.vssettings file path from Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Import and Export Settings. Open CurrentSetings.vssettings xml file and find and remove all your addin related elements. Then restart visual studio 2012 IDE.